# Error trying to verify a tweepy API using 3 legged OAuth. Error 401

Tags: python, error-handling, oauth, tweepy

I am trying to use twitter's 3-legged OAuth to tweet using a twitter bot that I made, on a different twitter account. After going through the tweepy documentation (https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/authentication.html#legged-oauth) for 3-legged OAuth, I ended up with the following code:

```
import tweepy    

consumer_key = 'XMNB5a0cuHOrko2ETCqs8iT4p'
consumer_secret = 'm46XTiR9JkYXWEoHWZwyemQJ5V5JW448KzovQWnpWNglTVUmjz'
callback_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/'


oauth1_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    consumer_key, consumer_secret,
    callback= callback_url
)

print(oauth1_user_handler.get_authorization_url())
```

After printing the URL to grant the bot access to my other twitter account, the website redir
http://127.0.0.1/?oauth_token=IsmSagAAAAABhOTpAAABg2xaxX4&oauth_verifier=QK7sVI3A8i0wsUR59s4MiGPMFJejzWcr

```
 access_token, access_token_secret = oauth1_user_handler.get_access_token(
    'QK7sVI3A8i0wsUR59s4MiGPMFJejzWcr'
)
```

Next I passed the end of the URL into this portion of the code, where it asks for the OAuth Verifier. When I run this, I get an error.

"raise TweepyException(e)

tweepy.errors.TweepyException: Token request failed with code 401, response was 'Error processing your OAuth request: Invalid oauth_verifier parameter'."

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here or what the issue. If anyone has an experience with this or 3-legged OAuth or any other suggestions on how to tweet on a different account, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/twitterdev/enterprise-scripts-python/blob/main/Engagement-API/generate_user_access_tokens.py) code sample from twitterdev, which uses a PIN-based version of the 3-legged OAuth process, worked for me.

Following the instructions in the code linked above should allow you to generate an access token and access token secret for the account you are trying to tweet with. You should then be able to use these, along with your consumer key and secret, for OAuth 1.0 authentication.